# What is the maximum length for a querystring?

Tags: http, iis, query-string, uri

I'm using HTTP requests in my program to pass data via a querystring  to a web-based status page.  The requests are of the form:

```
http://www.example.com/poststatus.asp?ID="FRED"&widgetscompleted=1234&...parameterN=valueN
```

The ASP page parses the querystring and updates a database.

My question is: what is the sensible length limit of the querystring?  I've seen mention of 2000-odd bytes but that seems to be browser-related and there is no browser involved here - just my app (using Indy) and IIS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the maximum possible length of a query string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string)

Comment: Thanks @James.  Indeed that one answers the question: `Microsoft Internet Information Server (Server)
The default limit is 16,384 characters (yes, Microsoft's web server accepts longer URLs than Microsoft's web browser). This is configurable.`  That answer wasn't thrown up as a candidate when I entered the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browser dependent, for more [this](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html) might help

Answer (score 1):

With the limitation on characters, what i usually do is minimize the querystring values from your example:  &widgetscompleted= could be abreviated to &wc=.

I am certain if you minimize these, the length shouldn't be an issue.